# Scala - get BSON document size with new ReactiveMongo(2.13)

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I want to find out the BSON document size before updating the document, using Scala and
reactiveMongo  - [lib](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reactivemongo/reactivemongo).

Working with the old lib(2.12) the equivalent code  -

```
val bsonDoc = EntityBSONHandler.write(entity)
      val size = BSONDocumentBufferHandler
        .write(bsonDoc, ChannelBufferWritableBuffer())
        .toReadableBuffer()
        .size
```

I could not figure out the new implementation with version 2.13 or later.

Thank you.

Comment: Why? what the purpose?

Comment: It looks like all the low-level functions to work with BSON (in its encoded binary form) have been made private now.

Comment: @Thilo any alternative that I can use?

Comment: Look like an X/Y question. You think you need to get the size, but you don't explain what the "real" goal/need.